# SSL Error when using OWASP Zap as proxy for Genymotion

Tags: ssl, genymotion, owasp, zap

I want to use Genymotion as my Android emulator and I intend to attach the OWASP Zap (localhost:8080) as its proxy but I encountered an SSL error.
[image]

Can someone help me with this issue?

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Just hit continue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add OWASP Zap root certificate to the Virtual Device Android OS, the same way as with BURP suite. You can take inspiration from this example: https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012333077-How-to-use-Burp-suite-with-Genymotion-Desktop-

Comment: I followed the instructions the link you shared. However, when I tried to put 127.0.0.1 as the proxy host and search anything in browser, I encounter  ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error. Does this mean my emulator can't reached the localhost proxy?